# How ro reset fedora?

Tags: linux, unix, fedora

I want to reset Fedora so it appears as it was reinstalled, but without the cd.

I have many issues with it so I want to start with a blank page ! :D

Is it posible to do this in fedora, without reinstalling it from cd ?

I dont want to save any files !!!

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Possible if you have fedora running in `Virtual Machine` and have `snapshot backup`. Or you have full system backup.

Comment: No I need to reset whole system ://

Comment: short answer not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

When you were using your Fedora distribution, were you using it as a regular (non-root) user? Or were you using it as the root user?

Non-root users are normally only allowed to modify files within their home directory. That means if you were using your Fedora as a non-root user, any changes you've made are confined to your home directory. You can simply delete that directory and recreate it, and the end result will be as if it's a new Fedora installation.